# Storing output from for loop into empty array

Tags: r

I have a four dimensional empty array called "output" the dimensions are

```
dim(output)
[1] 192  94  12 160
```

I also have a for loop for 160 iterations producing an array on each iteration called "XX". The dimensions are. 
   dim(XX)
   [1] 192  94  12

I want to store each of the 160 iterations of XX, one into each of the 1:160 
fourth dimensions

Can you help?

Comment: `for(i in 1:160) {some stuff; output[, , ,i] <- results}` where results is an array of dimension 192 X 94 X 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each iteration of the loop doesn't depend on a previous one, you could use `vapply`. Just take the loop's code and make a function which returns an array with dimensions `c(192, 94, 12)`. This would be *much* faster than a `for` loop.

```
myfun <- function(i) {
    array(i, c(192, 94, 12))  # Replace with actual code
}

output <- vapply(1:160, myfun, array(0, c(192, 94, 12)))
```

In the `vapply` call, replace the first argument of `array` with the same data type you want for `output` (e.g., logical, numeric (as in the example), or character).